# Using non-parametric transformation (ranking) on variables for factor analysis in R

Tags: r, nonparametric, factor-analysis, mixed-type-data

I have been wrestling with how to simplify a set of mixed variables (some orthogonal, some numeric) some (of both types) of which are significantly skewed.  I have run a factor analysis anyway and have some promising results, but obviously I am concerned about having valid results.  There are eight variables, 4 orthogonal and 4 numeric, with 83 subjects.  This involves a study of yoga/lifesyle practices.  I am looking to have factors that simplify the set of 2 meditation variables (daily amount and years of practice), time doing yoga exercises, diet, sexual habits, sleep, plus health and age.

My understanding is that using a non-parametric transformation at the start such as ranking, and others, would be inappropriate because it changes the relationships (correlations) among the variables. In the factor analysis that I ran, I used the hetcor function to create a correlation matrix from the mixed data and then ran fa (gls method) with a varimax rotation and Thurstone factor score generation.  It gave strong loadings and explained 75% of the variance.  In contrast, I tried using a Kendall based correlation matrix, not calling any variable a factor, and got weaker loadings and only 43% of the variance explained.

Are either of the above approaches appropriate?  Is there a better alternative?  And ultimately, to generate factor scores, is there a way to generate the latent factor scores from the factor weights and the non-normal raw scores?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by an orthogonal variable?

Comment: Can you clarify what you intended to convey by "non-parametric variable"?

Comment: The four orthogonal variables are on a 5 point ordered Likert-like scale.

Comment: By non-parametric variable, I was considering using a ranking of all the variables to overcome issues with significant skewness in some of the variables and then running the factor analysis.  Other transformations that I have tried do not seem sufficient and they complicate a factor analysis as well.  That would put all of the variables, as well, on the same scale.  However, that is essentially accomplished if using a Kendall based correlation matrix.

Comment: I am not sure how it would be possible to generate useful factor scores out of such rankings unless all subsequent analyses are done using non-parametric procedures.  While perhaps an extreme approach, is it conceivable?  Generating factor scores from factor analysis of a hetcor matrix also seems unclear.  I am unsure how a standardization process would work.

Comment: For the record, I have found one reference doing exactly what I have asked about (files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED355281.pdf), although it uses Spearman rather than Kaufman.  Other approaches exist using Bayesian analyses.